# CL/sycl.hpp not located by VS Code (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intel-oneapi, sycl

I am starting with SYCL and my code runs well. However in the VS Code editor,`#include<CL/sycl.hpp>` is showing error squiggles and I need to update the include path to get the auto-suggestions. However I am unable to locate where the file is. I did a normal installation `sudo apt install intel-basekit` to get SYCL on my machine.

Comment: You seem not to follow the instructions after the installation https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-oneapi-base-linux/top.html

Comment: @273K I am following the documentation as mentioned by you, but still the error squiggles are present. My code is compiling fine

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the error that you are facing?  And also, are you able to run your code successfully or not?

Comment: Please do follow the steps mentioned in the video [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=running+oneAPI+code+in+VSCode&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN941IN941&oq=running+oneAPI+code+in+VSCode&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160.385654j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_myUDY532E-WU3LUPgcOO6A815)

Answer (score 2):

I have exact same environment. You can see the steps in the video link that Varsha posted.

But to make more direct,
Right Click on Squiggly lines, edit include path. Either through GUI or click link to c_cpp_properties.json

Add the following:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/include/**"
            ],
```